# Relativsatz mit 'mittels'

Tags: genitive, relative-clause

Ich bin mir nicht sicher, welche der folgenden Varianten korrekt ist:

> die Transformation, mittels derer ...

oder

> die Transformation, mittels deren ...

Rein grammatikalisch betrachtet vermute ich, dass die erste Variante richtig sein sollte (Mittels + Genetiv; Genetiv Sg. von *die* ist *derer*), aber irgendwie "klingt es komisch".

Der gesamte Satz wäre:

> Im Folgenden wird die Lorentz-Transformation vorgestellt, mittels derer die Maxwell-Gleichungen in allen Inertialsystemen gelten.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Mittels derer* ist richtig und klingt für mich auch gar nicht ungewöhnlich. Dass es da heute Unsicherheiten gibt, die "mittels deren" fast schon zu einer akzeptablen Variante machen, spüre ich allerdings auch.

Ich nehme an, das Problem ist, dass *derer* heute nur noch in einem derartigen Kontext vorkommt und auch dort recht selten ist. Das Wort *deren* wird dagegen im Google-Corpus etwa zehnmal so oft verwendet und kommt insbesondere auch häufig hinter *mittels* vor. (Korrekt etwa in *Mittels deren Eigenschaften können wir...*.)

... soweit meine spontane Reaktion. Aber dann habe ich in Googles n-gram-Viewer gesehen, dass *mittels derer* und *mittels deren* früher etwa gleich häufig waren, ungefähr in der Zeit 1830-1950 *mittels deren* wesentlich häufiger als *mittels derer*, und erst in der letzten Zeit *mittels derer* wesentlich häufiger als *mittels deren* wurde. Wahrscheinlich nicht zuletzt deshalb, weil dadurch die von Thorsten Dittmar genannte Unterscheidung klarer wird. (Meine Stichprobe von Texten vor 1950 zeigt, dass damals auch Thorsten Dittmars erste Variante mit *mittels deren* formuliert wurde, evt. in Analogie zu anderen Genitiv-Konstruktionen auf *-n* wie z.B. in *einer/s jeden*.)

Ich bin nicht 100% sicher, zu verstehen, was da los ist, aber es sieht so aus, als ob es früher eine Art Sonderregel gegeben hätte die inzwischen am Verschwinden ist. Sonderregel deshalb, weil *mittels großen* im Gegensatz zu *mittels großer* offenbar nie wirklich gebräuchlich war.

Meine ersten beiden Absätze lasse ich als eindrucksvolle Demonstration der [recency illusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recency_illusion) stehen.

Comment: Ich glaube, das Problem rührt auch daher, dass Menschen aus unerfindlichen Gründen Probleme mit Relativsätzen zu haben scheinen und sich dann aus Umformulierungen Dinge herleiten. Wenn ich nämlich sage *Im folgenden wird ... vorgestellt, mit deren Hilfe ...*, dann komme ich eventuell zu dem Schluss *mittels deren* könnte auch korrekt sein.

Answer (score 2):

Wenn man deinen letzten Beispielsatz nimmt, dann auf jeden Fall *mittels derer*. Du würdest *mittels deren* verwenden, wenn eine Eigenschaft der Lorentz-Transformation beschrieben würde.

Zum Beispiel:

> Hier setzt man eine Lokomotive ein, mittels derer Eisenbahnwaggons bewegt werden.
>   Hier setzt man eine Lokomotive ein, mittels deren Kraft bis zu ... Waggongs gezogen werden können.

Comment: @emanuel Beispiele angepasst.

Answer (score 0):

Man müßte dem Fragesteller schon sagen, dass "mittels derer" schwerfällig und geziert altertümlich klingt. "mit deren Hilfe die Maxwell Gleichungen in allen ... Systemen verwendet werden können - das klingt einfacher und natürlicher.

Comment: Du kannst es ihm sagen, wenn es Deine Meinung ist; wessen Meinung es nicht ist, der muss es ihm auch nicht sagen.

Comment: Das wäre natürlich auch eine Möglichkeit... (warum ich da bloß nicht dran gedacht habe :o)

Vielleicht liegt das "komisch klingen" für mich ja gar nicht am deren, sondern am mittels...

Comment: Ich find "mittels derer" super fluffig und zeitgemäß und viel schöner als "mittels deren Hilfe"...